# getting current document address (firefox extension)

Tags: javascript, dom

does anybody know, how to get URI of current page/tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`window.location.href` holds the URI of the window’s document.

Comment: OK, thank you. <pre>content.location.href</pre> show me the URI of the page :)

Answer (score 4):

[This page](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=456173&p=2454609) seems to have what you are looking for

and [this one](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?p=2442799#2442799) may have more info that you will find useful

Answer (score 3):

The accepted answer here is incorrect, but the comment associated with it is a lot closer.

The FAQ linked in phsr's page links to "Getting document of currently selected tab", but Mozilla changed all their links without retaining backwards compatibility, and thus breaking a lot of reference sites.

The correct URL is: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Extension_Code_Snippets/Tabbed_Browser#Getting_document_of_currently_selected_tab

This document explains how to get the document object as you'd expect to get in web-side Javascript.

Given than, you can easily ask for `gBrowser.contentDocument.location.href` or `content.document.location.href`. If your use-case is more complex than a script running on the active tab (eg Your script is running in a pop-up XUL window) then you're best to read the FAQ linked above.